What is the best way to use `ModelChoiceField` in `NestedTabularInline`
Recently, I've noticed that the detail screen in my web has been performing very slowly. After analyzing the issue, I found that it's caused by an inline containing a ModelChoiceField when number of instances too large. This field repeatedly executes SELECT * queries to the database, significantly slowing down the screen's loading time.
Eg: That inline have 50 instances, now it has 50 ModelChoiceField that's ramping 50 SELECT *
I tried various solutions, including setting the queryset to objects.none()
However, this approach led to a new problem: when editing, the data doesn't auto-select as expected. I attempted to address this by setting the initial value dynamically in the __init__ method, but it didn't work due to the lack of a queryset.
class CustomDuplicateItemInlineForm(forms.ModelForm):
    # extra fields
    action = forms.CharField(
        label='Action Duplicate',
        required=False,
        widget=DuplicateLinkWidget(),
        )

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

    def clean_action_link(self):
        return self.cleaned_data['action']

class CustomOptionSelect2(autocomplete.Select2):
    def render(self, name, value, attrs=None, renderer=None):
        html = super().render(name, value, attrs, renderer)
        create_link = '<a href="/admin/sbase/podoption/add/" target="_blank">Create new PodOptions</a>'
        return mark_safe(f"{html}<br>{create_link}")

class CustomDuplicateItemInline(nested_admin.NestedTabularInline):
    class Media:
        js = ('js/custom/admin_inlines/duplicate_inline_item.js',)

class ProductOptionInline(CustomDuplicateItemInline):
    verbose_name = 'Config Product Option'
    verbose_name_plural = 'Config Product Options'
    model = ProductOption
    extra = 0
    form = ProductOptionForm
    formset = ProductOptionFormSet

class ProductOptionForm(CustomDuplicateItemInlineForm):
    class Meta:
        model = ProductOption
        fields = '__all__'

    # override option để hiển thị autocomplete với size option
    option = forms.ModelChoiceField(
        queryset=PodOption.objects.none(),
        required=True,
        widget=CustomOptionSelect2(
            url='product-size-options-auto-complete',
        ),
        label='Size Option'
    )

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ProductOptionForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        # Use the preloaded data to set the initial dynamically
        if self.instance and self.instance.pk and hasattr(self, 'product_size_options'):
            self.fields['option'].initial = self.product_size_options[self.instance.option_id]  # Manually set the result cache

It's all empty as you can see

If anyone knows the solution, please let me know. Thanks in advance!

Use queryset=PodOption.objects.all(), and work with the select2 widget.

@willeM_VanOnsem I do use select2 widget, the objects.all() is the main problem of too many query access

well there is a Select2 that works with a lookup making an AJAX call, but likely you are not using that one.

see https://django-select2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/django_select2.html

@willeM_VanOnsem I think you misunderstood my question, it's not about Ajax, it's about heavy amount of ModelChoiceField created by inline

@willeM_VanOnsem I updated example for clearing the issue

no, I get that, but the queryset=... itself is not why it hits the database that much: it is by selecting a widget that forces the queryset to get evaluated. So by using a select2 with a lookup, you don't populate the form, you let AJAX perform searches when needed.

can you share the CustomDuplicateItemInlineForm and CustomOptionSelect2 classes?

I updated my code @willeM_VanOnsem

After some debugging, it seems filter_choices_to_render of autocomplete.Select2 is the one causing trouble, so I override it with pre-loaded value. This method doesn't look good but it's worked for now
class CustomOptionSelect2(autocomplete.Select2):

    def filter_choices_to_render(self, selected_choices):
        """Override filter_choices_to_render to prevent access database on initial."""
        if hasattr(self, 'initial'):
            value = ModelChoiceIteratorValue(
                self.initial.pk, self.initial
            )
            self.choices = [
                (value, f"{self.initial.type}: {self.initial.value}")
            ]
        else:
            super().filter_choices_to_render(selected_choices)

